# Why doesn't Video JS play video with on.click event on Mobile?

Tags: javascript, video, video.js

I am using a Django Template for the html, so kindly ignore the variable insertions.
This works fine on everything, but mobile.

```
<video class="video-js vjs-big-play-centered" controls preload="auto"
                       poster="{% thumbnail video.thumbnail_image 960x0 %}" data-setup="{'fluid': true, nativeControlsForTouch: true}">

                  {% get_local_formats video.format_info_sources LANGUAGE_CODE as language_formats %}
                  {% for format in language_formats %}
                    <source src="{{ format.url }}" type="video/{{ format.suffix }}">
                  {% endfor %}

                  {% sort_subtitles video.all_subtitles LANGUAGE_CODE as sorted_subtitles %}
                  {% for subtitle in sorted_subtitles %}
                    <track kind="captions" src="{{ subtitle.url }}" srclang="{{ subtitle.lang }}"
                           label="{{ subtitle.language }}"
                           {% if forloop.first and subtitle.lang != video.language %}default{% endif %}>
                  {% endfor %}
                  <p class="vjs-no-js">
                    To view this video please enable JavaScript, and consider upgrading to a browser that <a
                      href="http://videojs.com/html5-video-support/" target="_blank">supports HTML5 video</a>
                  </p>
```

This is the JS part, since I am using a custom Play Button.

```
 $('.cms-video-play-button').on('click', function(event) {
    $(this).hide();
    $(this).prev('.video-preview').hide();
    $(this).next('.video-js').show().find('.vjs-poster').click();
    event.preventDefault();
  });
```

When I tap on the play button on mobile, the button still disappears, so I expect the click event is still triggered. It's just not playing the video. The `.vjs-poster` is in the DOM though.

Could someone please give me an idea of what my mistake is? Thank you very much for reading!

Comment: Does the console show any errors in the browser?

Comment: What is the device? Android? iOS? What is the video format?

Comment: Device: iPhone 6s ||
Console: No error messages